# Be-verbs modified by adverbs?

Tags: sentence-construction, functions

Could you please tell me what the function of the adverb "partly" is in the sentence, "It is partly her fault"? In other words, what does "partly" modify in that sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Since it’s an adverb, “partly” is modifying the verb — “is”. That is to say “it is her fault, but only in part, not *entirely* her fault”.

Comment: Thanks for replying. However, isn't "is" used as a "linking verb" in that sentence?

Comment: Yes, I suppose it is. Nevertheless, if I were to say “the house is partly green”, what else is “partly” modifying, if not “is”?

Comment: Hi Mat, thanks for keeping up with this post. I really appreciate that. Regarding the above sentence, "partly" is used to modify the linking Verb "to be" then. I still find it hard to get though, as I've always taught that linking verbs are followed by adjectives (or Nouns).

Comment: They can also be followed by an adverb: “Ted is _often_ late”, “apples are _usually_ red”, “the room is _brightly_ colored”, and so on.

Comment: Hi again, regarding the adverbs in the following sentences, “the house is partly green”, “Ted is often late”, “apples are usually red”, isn't each adverb used to modify the adjective (green, late, red) after it? What about the adverb in the sentence, "It is partly her fault." I thought it perhaps either modify for the whole sentence or the verb "to be" (which I find rarely seen).